# Creating folder on Office 365 using Java Spring boot

Tags: java, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, office365, spring-resttemplate

I want to create a folder inside an item on office 365 sharepoint using Java.
The request to be hit is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/children
```

And the body of the request is to be:

```
{
  "name": "Folder Name",
  "folder": {}
}
```

For the Rest call (POST) to be made, I need help on how to initialize this "folder": {} for sending the request. I tried forming a JSON String or creating a DTO, but getting 400: Bad Request each time.

Comment: What is the type of the item specified by item-id? Check if the folder with the same name already exists inside the item. Content-Type must be application/json

Comment: Thank you. Adding 'Content-Type: application/json' in request header worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Reference code snippet:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

DriveItem driveItem = new DriveItem();
driveItem.name = "Folder name";
Folder folder = new Folder();
driveItem.folder = folder;

graphClient.drives("drive id").items("item id").children()
    .buildRequest()
    .post(driveItem);
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anything else I can help with regarding this issue?

You can comment us at any time and we will continue to follow up.

Thanks,
Carl Zhao